# Normal Mapping Artifacts

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Part of my brick texture that is using a normal map, is showing artifacts when I raised the Normal Map Strength above 0.3. I'm using Blender v2.82 and Cycles rendering, Nvidia 1070.[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: where are the artefacts you're talking about? Maybe share your file

Comment: The brick wall texture, part is bump mapped the other is just lines. If you look at the direct center of my image, that part of the brick wall is messed up.

Comment: Could be a bad normal map. Check to make sure the normal looks good. Might need to make an new one.

Comment: maybe share your file (with the images packed inside): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: you need to add UVs to your texture node

Comment: UVs? like a UV Map node? I tried adding a Mapping to the vector input

Comment: figured it out, I had to set the normal map texture to repeating